# Prove that the function $f$ is injective .

Tags: calculus

we have function $f(n): \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ that has following property

$\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N} \qquad f(f(m) + f(n)) = m + n$

how can I prove that this function is one to one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose 
\begin{align*}
f(a)&= f(b)\\
f(a)+f(c)&= f(b)+f(c)\\
f(f(a)+f(c))&= f(f(b)+f(c))\\
a+c &=b+c\\
a&=b.
\end{align*}

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that depending whether if by definition $0$ is in $\mathbb{N}$, then $f$ is also surjective (otherwise the image is $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$).

Comment: @Nex But $f$ might be $x \mapsto x$ :) which is surjective in either case. (Terminology) And there really shouldn't be any confusion about what $\mathbb{N}$: it contains $0$. The set of integers greater than $0$ is $\mathbb{N}_+$.

Comment: @BrianO I guess the part in brackets should have read "otherwise the image contains $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\}$"

Comment: @Nex Ah ok that works.

Comment: @BrianO I would agree that it would be better if there was no confusion but that is simply not the case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation

Comment: @Nex I meant $\mathbb{N}^+$ not subscript. But no really, I that  $\mathbb{N}$ means the nonnegative integers unless otherwise specified by someone who wants to be perverse for perversion's sake. I can't think of one significant author who excludes $0$ from \mathbb{N} (dollar signs intentionally excluded), starting with Bourbaki who invented the "blackboard bold" name $\mathbb{N}$ as well as $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{C}$. It's the structure for arithmetic, which contains $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30804/discussion-between-nex-and-briano).